# Differential Equation Exact and Integrating Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the Differential Equation (DE) $( pxy^2 + qy )dx + (qx^2y + px)dy = 0$,

a) Show that DE is exact if $p = q$.

b) Hence or otherwise, solve the DE if $p = q = 2$.

c) If $p\neq q$, find an integrating factor in the form of $x^ry^s$, where $r = f_1(p,q)$ , $s = f_2(p,q)$. In other words, $r$ and $s$ are functions that can be expressed in terms of $p$ and $q.$

d) Hence or otherwise, solve the DE if $p = 2$, $q = 3$. Express your answer in the form of $x^ay^b - x^cy^d = w$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $w$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ChristinaKerr Easy to see that for $ F(x,y) = x^2y^2 + 2xy $ part b) can be written as $$ dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy = 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Given the Differential Equation (DE)

$\tag 1 ( pxy^2 + qy )dx + (qx^2y + px)dy = 0,$

a) Show that DE is exact if $p=q$. Substituting $p = q$ into $(1)$ yields:

$\tag 2 ( qxy^2 + qy )dx + (qx^2y + qx)dy = 0$

Now, take the $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  (qx^2y + qx)$ and compare that to $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  (qxy^2 + qy)$.

What do you get?

b) Hence or otherwise, solve the DE if $p=q=2$.

Substituting $p = q = 2$ into $(1)$ yields:

$\tag 3 ( 2xy^2 + 2y )dx + (2x^2y + 2x)dy = 0$

How did you learn to solve this type of DE?

c) Do you know how to find an integrating factor?

d) Substituting $ p=2, q=3$ into $(pxy^2+qy)dx+(qx^2y+px)dy=0$, yields:

$\tag 4 (2xy^2+3y)dx+(3x^2y+2x)dy=0$

Part c) is using the integrating factor. Do you know how to use that to help find the form they provided?

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you - this one needed to show some more work, so I decided to provide hints and see if the guidance and work can start. No followup. :-( oh well!

Comment: We can only do our best...and hope, at some point, if not now, for future users, it will be useful to others!